# Using structures to set the functions

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel, kernel-module

While writing  kernel modules/drivers, most of the time some structures are initialized to point to some specific functions. As a beginner in this could someone explain the importance of this.

I saw the `struct file_operations` while writing the character device driver

Also I found that eventhough the functions are declared they are not implemented always. Could anyone help on that too. For example, in the kernel source: kernel/dma.c, eventhough

```
static const struct file_operations proc_dma_operations = {
    .open       = proc_dma_open,
    .read       = seq_read,
    .llseek     = seq_lseek,
    .release    = single_release,
};
```

are defined, only proc_dma_open is implemented.

Comment: No, the other functions (seq_read, seq_lseek and single_release) are simply implemented elsewhere.

Comment: @fge I couldnt find `seq_read`, `single_release`, `seq_lseek` in either dma.c, dma.h or seq_file.h in kernel source.  ``

Comment: This example is somewhat "strange". Usually, when filling such structures, you fill them with pointers to your functions. Here, you use some "standard" functions (seq_xxx, implemented in fs/seq_file.c) and your own function (proc_dma_open).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions `seq_read`, `seq_lseek` and `single_release` are declared in the kernel source file `linux-3.1.6/include/linux/seq_file.h` and defined in the kernel source file `linux-3.1.6/fs/seq_file.c`. They are probably common to many file operations.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever played with object-oriented languages like C++, think of `file_operations` as a base class, and your functions as being implementations of its virtual methods.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers to functions are a very powerful tool in the C language that allows for real-time redirect of function calls. Most if not all operating systems have a similar mechanism, like for example the infamous INT 21 functions 25/35 in the old MS-DOS that allowed TSR programs to exist.

In C, you can assign the pointer to a function to a variable and then call that function through that variable. The function can be changed either at init time based on some parameters or at runtime based on some behavior.

Here is an example:

```
int fn(int a)
{
   ...
   return a;
}

...

int (*dynamic_fn)(int);
...
dynanic_fn = &fn;
...
int i = dynamic_fn(0);
```

When the pointer "lives" in a structure that can be passed to system calls, this is a very powerful feature that allows hooks into system functions.

In object oriented languages, the same kind of behavior can be achieved by using reflection to instantiate classes dynamically.